# Password Hash function throwing error 1146

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a query like this

```
UPDATE `database`.`user` 
SET `Password`=Password("test1234!@#$") 
WHERE `UserID`='1234';
```

I ran this once and it updated the Password fine. I changed the case of the t in test and it started to fail with the message

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'database.Unknown' doesn't exist.

After some experimentation I found that removing the `$` in the string allowed the query to run successfully. I attempted to escape the character with / but the error still occurred. The collation on the column is `utf8` and it is `varchar(50)`.

The query itself is being executed in `MySQL Workbench 5.2.47` and on `MySQL version 5.1.62` Community Edition.

Can anyone enlighten me on why the $ is being troublesome.

EDIT: It is now occurring without any of the special characters. I also am aware there are much safer ways of hashing passwords. I am just curious at this point why the specific error is occurring.

Comment: You should use `\\`` instead of `/` to escape char

Comment: Is the [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) option activated on your server?

Comment: Why are you using this function anyway? Note that it is not recommended to use for application passwords, and should only be used to alter MySQL user passwords. For hashing passwords of your application users use bcrypt hashing if possible.

Comment: I am aware it is a bad function use I am just curious in this case why it isn't functioning as I would expect. At any rate after trying different escapes and checking ANSI_QUOTES the problem occurs without any of the special characters in the query.

Comment: Is this being calped from php? Can you paste the php line as well that executes this? Im guessing something to do with the quote/apostrophe/backticks that you are using. A backtick ` is not the same as an apostrophe '  for mysql.

Comment: This is being executed directly in MySQL workbench.

Comment: I call mysql workbench buggy at best. Have you tried restarting it. And your db name is actually `database` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried restarting it and no the database is not actually called database since that would be silly. There seems to be another issue where the columns are no longer listed as well. I might try reinstalling workbench if problems persist.

Answer (score 1):

First deduct the issue is from workbench:
Log in from command prompt (mysql -u Username -pPassword -h hostname) or with phpmyadmin and then try executing the query.

If that works, it's the workbench.

Then you might first want to just delete all configured connection settings in the workbench and re-adding them. This might already solve your problem.

If the problem maintains, you can try to re-install workbench.

Comment: I checked it in the command prompt and the issue still was occurring. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being that a trigger existed that had this in it

```
INSERT INTO Unknown VALUES(1);
```

I don't know what the purpose of this is but it obviously was causing the issue. Thanks for the help regardless everyone.